# CGAffineTransform not working correctly

Tags: xcode, cocoa, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I want my transform to scale the image whilst translating it, is it possible to do in the same method?

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:annKey context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xx, yy);
    image.transform = scale;
    image.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate the two transforms using `CGAffineTransformConcat` to translate *and* scale your view. You're currently just replacing the scale transformation with the translation.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3796238/573626) has an example. You can also look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat).